# Fill для внешнего SVG файла в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack

Есть ли какой-то способ изменить цвет SVG файла если тот был импортирован из внешнего SVG файла? То есть `<img src="[svgfile]">` не позволяет контроллировать цвет, а добавляя SVG код каждой иконки в React сильно замусорит его. Я пытаюсь понять как красиво и удобно импортировать все иконки в проект.

У меня сейчас примерно следующий код:

```
<buttonWrapper>
    <button iconBefore={facebookIcon}>Facebook</button>
</buttonWrapper>
```

`facebookIcon` должен быть строчный SVG элемент с своими параметрами и возможностью контроллировать цвет, так есть при наведении цвет будет меняться.

Я хочу получить что-то в этом роде:

```
import icon from "./icons/user.svg"

<icon fill="red" />
```

Пока что поиск ничего полезного не дал, многие варианты лишь портят структуру кода да и в принципе много вариантов я не нашел. Может кто подскажет что делать в такой ситуации?

Меня по сути интересует как удобно и гибко писать код что бы таких вопросов больше не возникало. Из-за большого колличества расширений в проекте уже сложная структура и усложнять ее дальше страшновато.

Answer (score 1):

я Делал 2 варианта, и оба имеют право на жизнь

1 - выделить `<BaseIcon />` - выставляет свойства svg, выводит чилда который svg

```
const ArrowUP = (props) => {
    return <BaseIcon {...props}>ВОТ ТУТ SVG код</BaseIcon>
}
```

всё это дело сложить в папочку `Icons` - разместить там файлик `index.js` с содержимым

```
export {default as ArrowUp} from 'путь к иконке ArrowUp';
export {default as ArrowDown} from 'путь к иконке ArrowDown';
```

в итоге импорт будет простым и приятным

```
import {ArrowUp, ArrowDown} from 'путь к папке Icons'
```

- этот способ применён в MaterialUI

2 - Это запихнуть svg в шрифт и вот так будет выглядеть вызов `<span className="arrowUP" />`, т.к. иконка будет шрифтом, то цвет ширину линий можно будет без проблем регулировать

Comment: Я не понял каким образом сделать шрифт и что за функция в начале ответа. Это такую функцию создавать для каждой иконки? Не могли бы вы составить небольшой пример с 2-3 иконками с разными цветами, это был бы шикарный ответ!